# Optimizing Amazon RDS - MySQLTuner Recommendations / Feedback & Suggestions

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, amazon-rds, query-performance

I'm currently trying to optimize a database I've inherited for speed. 
The server is an Amazon RDS **db.m3.large** instance:

- 2 VCPUs
- 7.5 GB Memory
- 500 GB HDD

My current strategy is to do the following:

1. Remove all dev databases and push them to a different server
2. Add unique index on `aggr_id` column in the problematic tables below (How to do this properly without interrupting production?)
3. Switch MyISAM tables to InnoDB to prevent locking (What are the implications of doing this?)

**I am making this post to get feedback on the current approach, and any additional ideas. I'm not a DBA by any means, just a web developer. Any and all feedback is welcomed, thanks in advance. I'll be sure to respond and approve answers! I will also edit this post with any insights gained and resources found.**

There are a few problem tables all with the same format:

```
| xxxxx | CREATE TABLE `xxxxx` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aggr_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `craft_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `task_year` smallint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hc1` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  ......
  `hc365` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`task_year`),
  KEY `IDX_AGGRLABORDAY` (`task_year`,`aggr_id`,`craft_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=50480037 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50500 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(task_year)
(PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2012) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2013) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2014) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (2015) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (2016) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (2017) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (9999) ENGINE = MyISAM) */
```

Here is an explain of a problematic query:

```
explain DELETE FROM xxxxx WHERE aggr_id = 3000010;
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | xxxxx                     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 46611048 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

Below is MySQLTuner results:

```
[--] Assuming 7680 MB of physical memory
[!!] Assuming 0 MB of swap space (use --forceswap to specify)
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.6.21-log

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM 
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 274G (Tables: 75)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 52)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 7G (Tables: 227)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 35

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 107d 15h 56m 50s (110M q [11.901 qps], 3M conn, TX: 14149B, RX: 108B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 58% / 42%
[--] Total buffers: 5.4G global + 1.5M per thread (604 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 6.2G (83% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (17K/110M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 29% (177/604)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/49.6G
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.4% (25B cached / 155M reads)
[!!] Query cache is disabled
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 2% (133K temp sorts / 6M sorts)
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 62% (7M on disk / 11M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 74% (945K created / 3M connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (1K open / 674K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 3% (2K/65K)
[!!] Table locks acquired immediately: 78%
[!!] InnoDB  buffer pool / data size: 5.3G/7.7G
[!!] InnoDB log waits: 1
-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: http://bit.ly/1mi7c4C
    Optimize queries and/or use InnoDB to reduce lock wait
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_type (=1)
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
    table_open_cache (> 2000)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 7G)
    innodb_log_buffer_size (>= 8M)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm writing this as I see your points; please read to the end before taking action.  I 'develop' the best answer piece by piece -- hope you learn some things.)

```
DELETE FROM xxxxx WHERE aggr_id = 3000010;
```

must scan every row in every partition.  That means it must do a lot of I/O, which will take a lot of time, regardless of the tuning.

If this is a common query, then add

```
INDEX(aggr_id)
```

Even better is change

```
KEY `IDX_AGGRLABORDAY` (`task_year`,`aggr_id`,`craft_id`)
```

Normally it is best to have the "partition key" (task_year) at the *end* of indexes, not the start.  In this case, you may as well simply remove it.  Any use of task_year will be for "pruning", then the KEY can take over.  DROP that INDEX and ADD the following in a single ALTER:

```
KEY `IDX_AGGRLABORDAY` (`aggr_id`,`craft_id`)
```

Caution: It will lock the table for some time.

You ought to switch to InnoDB, which has online INDEX operations.

The tuner suggestions seem to be worse than usual:

- Leave the query cache off
- raising the tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size is not necessarily useful
- You seem to be using a mixture of InnoDB and MyISAM, so I recommend innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2500M and key_buffer_size = 500M.  (The high buffer_pool setting was starving the data cache for MyISAM.)
- As for the tmp tables; let's see your slowest query, plus the SHOW CREATE TABLE.
- Ignore table fragmentation; don't bother OPTIMIZEing.
- table_open_cache should be a few hundred.  If open_files_limit is only 1K, then something in the OS is constraining the cache.

If aggr_id can be made UNIQUE, then perhaps it should be the PRIMARY KEY and eliminate `id`.  Note that you cannot have a UNIQUEness constraint because of partitioning.

Note that there are two things intertwined here:  Switching to InnoDB and making aggr_id the PK.  If you do both, then do

```
PRIMARY KEY (aggr_id, craft_id, task_year)
```

and have no secondary keys.  The rationale:

- InnoDB really needs a PK.
- task_year (the partition key) must be in every unique (that includes PK) key
- It is usually best to put the partition key last
- You apparently need craft_id for some other reason?  Quite possibly it should be removed, especially since the PK coexists with the data in InnoDB.  (Please show the SELECT(s) that wants craft_id; we can discuss this further.)

Switching to InnoDB is almost always "good".  See my blog for the gotchas:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb
While you are at it, read about PARTITION issues here:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint
It may conclude that partitioning is doing you no good.

If you go to all-InnoDB, then innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G and key_buffer_size = 20M.

Comment: Apologize for not getting back to you on this, give me a few more days and I'll type up a response.